# looking for an adverb for "without concealing a truth"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> he told me about it without concealing the truth

is there any adverb I can replace the prepositional phrase with?
I think frankly and honestly would work in the context but favoring the intention, I'm looking for an adverb that has a sense of "without concealing a truth".

Comment: "honestly", "plainly"

Comment: *openly* works nicely as an antonym of *concealing*

Comment: thank you!! @Jim@ tgdavies

Comment: If you guys have answers, you should write real answers instead of torpedoing questions like this.